# STASM or AAM which is more efficient

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, opencv, face-detection

I am working in face detection and recognition project. I am using STASM for face detction and locating face landmarks. On googling I found AAM (Active Appearance Model) and found that it is also used for face detection and locating face landmarks. Is AAM more efficient than STASM, can you provide your ideas like pros and cons between AAM and STASM or anyother better algorithm than these two?

Image input: Web-cam/secondary-cam of Ipad & Android Tablets/Phones

For the same set of training images - which one has greater range of performance w.r.t distance from camera/pose/illumination?